# Finding the matched value from a list

Tags: python, numpy

In a list, I need to find the nearest matched value (ex:1000).
[image]

to make it clear: The (figure) list values when they are plotted.
When I am using old solutions from StackOverflow like, findnearest,takeclosest every result showing only one index value =3675 (one wing side). I need both wing side value.
i.e for 1000 index values should show [2600 and 3675].
I tried : The dividing data into half and each time noting down the index value (each wing side).
code:

```
import numpy as np
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]
# Above code from stack overflow

a= np.where(min(alt)==alt))
x1=find_nearest(alt[alt[0]:alt[a]],1000)
x2=find_nearest(alt[alt[a]:alt[-1]],1000)
x1,x2 are two wing side values.
```

or is there any faster way approach.

Thank You

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the `numpy.where()` method:

```
idxs = np.where(yvals == 1000)
```

This will return a numpy array of all the instances where `yvals` is 1000.

Then you can obtain the `xvals` for those indexes.

```
xvals_seeked = xvals[idxs]
```

Comment: values are in float and I have to find by the nearest value approach only.